# how can I use lucid icons coming from a data page without getting the error: {$$typeof: ..., render: function}

Tags: reactjs, next.js, icons

#data page :

```
import { SliderContents } from "@/types/slider-contents";
import { CheckCircle } from '../icons/icons'

export const HowItWorks : SliderContents[] = [
  {
    id: 0,
    title: 'Découvrez comment ça marche',
    bgColor: 'bg-primary-200',
    Icon: CheckCircle
  },
...
```

#SliderContents

```
export interface SliderContents {
  id: number
  title?: string
  description?: string
  Icon?: React.ElementType
}
```

```
<div className="basis-1/3 h-[500px] bg-white rounded flex flex-col gap-10 justify-center items-center text-center">
          <Scroll contents={HowItWorks}/>
      </div >
```

#scroll

```
<div
        className={clsx("h-full bg-slate-900 content-scroll-animation")}
      >
        {
          contents?.map(({title, id, description, Icon}) =>
            <div key={id} className={clsx("w-full h-full slider bg-red-600 border-2 border-blue-800")}>
              <div className='flex flex-col justify-center items-center'>
                <div>
                  {
                    title ?
                    <Typography variant='title-base' component='h2'>
                      {title}
                    </Typography>
                    : null
                  }
                </div>
                <div>
                  <div>
                    {
                      description?
                      <Typography variant='title-base' component='p'>
                        {description}
                      </Typography>
                      : null
                    }
                    {
                      Icon ?
                      <Icon/>
                      : null
                    }
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          )
        }
      </div>
```

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2k17.png)

I would like to be able to display the icons in the carousel following the title and description. when I remove the icon it works correctly but when I put it back I get this error which appears